# How to encrypt data in Java using DES and decrypt that data into PHP

Tags: java, php, android, encryption

My Android application needs to encrypt data into java (using DES) and send that to server, at server side I am using PHP, so it will require to decrypt that data into PHP. So how it will be possible?

**Edited :** 
If AES should be better , then how can I make encryption and decryption methods which can work in JAVA as well as PHP.

*I did encryption and decryption in JAVA or PHP. But I have no idea about if I encrypt data into JAVA then how can I decrypt that data into PHP.*

Comment: DES has been broken [since 1998](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker). Use AES instead.

Comment: If you want to do this way use a encryption library supporting DES in java send it via a post request to the server and decrypt it there. But this sort of encryption is less safe than https .... ! So if you have the choice use HTTPS over DES encryption. Because everyone will be able to dissassemble your jar and identify the key. This is also the fact for AES.

Comment: I know the fact but I have no idea about how can I decrypt data into PHP with same method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encryption/decryption algorithms doesn't change, no matter which language you use. Just use the encryption and decryption libraries available in the corresponding languages, you should be fine.

Comment: Correct. The trickier part is getting the mode and padding scheme identical on both sides. One tip is to simply avoid using defaults. Always completely specify the mode and the padding scheme.